# No markdown-mode package available in emacs (spacemacs)

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

in https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/ at the installation section it says:

> The recommended way to install markdown-mode is to install the package
>   from MELPA Stable using package.el. First, configure package.el and
>   the MELPA Stable repository by adding the following to your .emacs,
>   init.el, or equivalent startup file:

```
(require 'package) (add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) (package-initialize)
```

So I added it to my `init.el`, then restarted `spacemacs`, then I hit `M-x` and `package-install` but i don't see any `markdown-mode` package, am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Here is my `init.el`:

```
;;; init.el --- Spacemacs Initialization File
;;
;; Copyright (c) 2012-2017 Sylvain Benner & Contributors
;;
;; Author: Sylvain Benner <sylvain.benner@gmail.com>
;; URL: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs
;;
;; This file is not part of GNU Emacs.
;;
;;; License: GPLv3

;; Without this comment emacs25 adds (package-initialize) here
;; (package-initialize)

;; Increase gc-cons-threshold, depending on your system you may set it back to a
;; lower value in your dotfile (function `dotspacemacs/user-config')
(setq gc-cons-threshold 100000000)

(defconst spacemacs-version         "0.200.13" "Spacemacs version.")
(defconst spacemacs-emacs-min-version   "24.4" "Minimal version of Emacs.")

(if (not (version<= spacemacs-emacs-min-version emacs-version))
    (error (concat "Your version of Emacs (%s) is too old. "
                   "Spacemacs requires Emacs version %s or above.")
           emacs-version spacemacs-emacs-min-version)
  (load-file (concat (file-name-directory load-file-name)
                     "core/core-load-paths.el"))
  (require 'core-spacemacs)
  (spacemacs/init)
  (configuration-layer/sync)
  (spacemacs-buffer/display-startup-note)
  (spacemacs/setup-startup-hook)
  (require 'server)
  (unless (server-running-p) (server-start)))

;; (org-babel-load-file "~/.emacs.d/configuration.org")

;; Additional...
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that spacemacs has it's own way of managing packages. I'd recommend simply loading the markdown layer, which should take care of installing the required packages

Simply add `markdown` to the list of layers your `.spacemacs`:

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(
  ;; ...
  ;; other layers
  markdown
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this (after asking for help somewhere else, documentation was not helpful) as it turns out it's one of the below options, either one of:

`M-x` -> customize-option -> org-export-backends checkbox on md

OR

Add to `(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()` (at file `~/.spacemacs`)

which can be accessed by `SPC f e d`

Then adding the following into `user-config` function:

`(setq org-export-backends '(ascii beamer html latex md))`

I really wonder why I got -6 it was not easy to find this especially as a newbie in emacs world.

Comment: In general, the spacemacs users hang out on reddit with the Emacs tag; whereas, here there are only die-hard programmers that expect to see a programming question with an example of code you tried and a request for help to fix it.  Configuration and installation questions in this forum are a hard-sell.  In general, https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ has participants who are more forgiving and more receptive.  Nowadays, I would likely only post a very complex programming question here relating to Emacs; e.g., a request for help writing an algorithm to calculate something complex ...